# Is there a way to fix the "content servers unreachable" error when running Steam via Wine BESIDES editing the config file/changing download region?

Tags: server, wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I am attempting to run Steam through Wine and install games from my library, but I keep getting the "content servers unreachable" prompt.

Background: I am trying to use Lutris for my runners rather than PlayOnLinux, but the error persists when trying to use both. Additionally, I'm using Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 on the latest stable release of the 4.17 kernel (as of now, that is 4.17.14 generic). The Linux version of Steam works fine and downloads games and data normally.

I've tried changing my download region as well as manually adding the content servers in the config.vdf file, but neither solution seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the version of wine in POL to version 3.8:

1. Go to Tools and under Wine versions (x86), choose 3.8 and add it to the right window, then close the window.
2. Next, click on Steam icon, and choose Configure. A PlayOnLinux Configuration window will show up and under General -> Wine version, choose 3.8